# Try out standard library <concepts> with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-concepts

GCC supports the `-fconcepts` switch, providing experimental core language concept features.

Is there also a way to use (an experimental version of) the  standard library implementation?

It would be great to have `std::derived_from`, `std::convertible_to`, `std::destructible` [and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/concepts) available when designing concepts.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept Fooable = requires(T f) {
    { bar(f) } -> std::convertible_to<float>;
};
```

Comment: If you use `-nostdlib` (or one of its [relatives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)), you can link whatever libraries you want instead of the standard/packaged ones that come with your toolchain. Or are you looking for something more than that?

Comment: There's some in the [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3) library.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not clarify the version of GCC. Actually starting from GCC 10 the concepts are supported with `-std=c++20` command-line option both by the compiler and  standard library implementation (libstdc++) coming with it. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9G5Y1KEeT

Comment: Thanks. At the time of posting, GCC 9.2 was the most current release.